# How to connect socket, and how to connect, emit and receive data from socket using php rest api. I am using codeigniter 3

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, sockets

Now I am developing a web application and doing REST API for mobile. The REST API is developed by using Codeigniter 3. Now I have a requirement to manage all notifications and alerts in web and mobile using sockets to make it real-time. Mobile app, its manageable using nodejs and javascript. In website also its manageable using javascript and socket.io or websocket.

Now from mobile and web, it can be accessing javascript, node js to socket with port 5000.
But how can I connect same socket server on same port and how to call emit and on events from REST API functions(PHP).

Is this possible?

Need help.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the API to connect to the websocket server as a client, and send/receive websocket messages?

Comment: I need to connect to socket server which is currently running on 5000 port. After connecting successfully, I need to send/receive web socket messages. These functions I need to do only from REST API functions. For eg. suppose mobile app team will call an api to update count of notification. I will update the count in database once request received in api. But at the same time I need to update count in ther connected socket server also. So that web/mobile front end team can collect count from socket in realtime.

Comment: Well certainly you can create a websocket client in PHP...there are a few libraries available for that, you can google them quite easily I think.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will check for available library.